# curl: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.1.0.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: curl, libssl

I tried to install MySQL 8 and ended up having this issue when i restarted, now, i can't use `curl`  etc on the system

OS Info
Ubuntu 14

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution here:
http://d.hatena.ne.jp/shammer/20161110/p1

```
find / -name libcurl.so.*
echo "/usr/local/lib" > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/libcurl.conf
ldconfig
curl
```

NOTE: In my case, libcurl.so.4 was found under "/usr/local/lib". If you find it under another location, update the code in line 2.